# What is the minimum graphics card that supports Windows Aero?

Tags: graphics-card, aero

I want transparency, mini previews when hover on taskbar buttons, etc.

The lowest graphics card that I've tested is an Nvidia GeForce 6100. I've found in the market GeForce FX5200/5500 but I don't know if it works. What is the minimum ATI/NVIDIA graphics card to support Windows Aero?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This information is available on the [Windows Vista System Requirements](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919183) page from Microsoft:

> A Windows Aero-capable graphics card is a graphics card that meets the following requirements:
>
> - Supports a Windows Display Driver
>     Model (WDDM) driver
> - Has a DirectX 9-class graphics
>     processor unit (GPU) that supports
>     Pixel Shader 2.0
> - Supports 32 bits per pixel
> - Passes the Windows Aero acceptance
>     test in the Windows Driver Kit (WDK)

Essentially, any GPU with DX9 and a driver that supports Aero will be capable of running all of the accelerated graphics features like window transparency, taskbar previews, etc. I have successfully run Windows Aero on an Nvidia FX5200, which you asked about in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Any Nvidia Geforce 5 or above should support it

Comment: This answer might help people with an Nvidia Geforce, but not others, like me (ATI card).